# android studio doesn't recognize downloaded ndk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv5K5.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKZpD.png)

after downloading the ndk i tried to select it but it said NDK does not contain any platforms.